# How do I install keras package in IronPython/VS2010?

Tags: ironpython

I get an error when trying to install keras:

> Installing 'keras' Unhandled exception: Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\runpy.py",
>   line 170, in run_module   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython
>   2.7\Lib\runpy.py", line 101, in _get_module_details   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 456, in get_loader
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 466,
>   in find_loader   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython
>   2.7\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 422, in iter_importers   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip__init__.py", line
>   13, in    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython
>   2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\exceptions.py", line 6, in    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython
>   2.7\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\six.py", line 701, in    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython
>   2.7\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\six.py", line 692, in exec_   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\runpy.py", line 109, in
>   _get_module_details AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_getframe'
>
> 'keras' failed to install. Exit code: 1

Answer (score 0):

(pasting what I wrote on Keras mailing list for your question, then extended)

It seems that IronPython does not support [setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099096/working-with-ptvs-ironpython-and-mongodb), which is used by Keras for installation. I've never used VisualStudio for Python, but it looks like you can use regular [CPython](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Selecting-and-Installing-Python-Interpreters) too. Try it.

As for now, I don't think you can make Keras work under IronPython, because its dependencies do not work there. [Theano doesn't](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/ABp7YwMpDIM) (this is from 2011, but I couldn't find any newer post), nor does [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18). So even if you somehow overcame the setuptools issue (e.g. by just copying files instead of using an installer), it would still be broken.