# Can python functions be called on different button clicks?

Tags: c#, python.net

I wish to call function1 from a python class in winform.button1_click_event() and then function2 from the same python class in winform.button2_click_event(). 
Note: function2 depends on function1 for data.
How can this be done ?

I cannot use IronPython since it doesn't support keras Visit [How do I install keras package in IronPython/VS2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328893/how-do-i-install-keras-package-in-ironpython-vs2010).

Class.py

```
  def load_Model_data(self):
    #Some code

  def Predict(self):
    #some code
```

Programme.cs

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           PythonEngine.Initialize();
            using (Py.GIL())
            {
                PyObject MyClass = PythonEngine.ImportModule("Class");

                Dynamic classTest = MyClass.GetAttr("ClassTest");
                               Dynamic tmp = classTest();
                tmp.load_Model_data;
           }

        }

void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Py.GIL())
            {
                PyObject MyClass = PythonEngine.ImportModule("Class");
                Dynamic classTest = MyClass.GetAttr("ClassTest");
                               Dynamic tmp = classTest();
                tmp.Predict();
           }
        }
```

on button2 click, the value in python code was not updated.

Comment: What *is the error*, please post as we can't help you if we don't know what the error is.

Comment: put breakpoints on all the lines in button2_click and then tell us which line it broke on and what the exact exception was.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ on clicking button2 the variable in python code did't have new value.

Comment: @hexagod i tried to reproduce the error , this time I didn't get it, however the variable in python code didn't have new value. Its empty

Comment: because you are creating a new class.

Comment: @MarkusDresch  So I need to declare class object  as a global variable, right ?

Comment: global in the sense of class scoped variable, yes. i don't know the details of python engine, but it may have to live longer than the button click as well.

Comment: @MarkusDresch I could resolve it. Thanks !